# Can a Multiplexer be used as a Demultiplexer

Tags: arduino, led, multiplexer, led-matrix

I'm trying to build a musical machine for myself. I've come to a situation where I want to control 8 LEDs using 3 selector pins on my 74151 IC. I've attached the circuit diagram below. Looks like I'll need a Demux instead of a Mux but I don't have any Demux IC on me. Is there a way I can achieve this using the IC 74151?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

In this example I've made S0,S1,S2 as high so X7 should glow. But it's not working. Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: A digital mux is a one way device. An analog mux using eg transmission gates connects an analog path between input and output. This is bidirectional unless analog unidirectional buffering is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [datasheet](https://www.esi.uclm.es/www/isanchez/apuntes/ci/74151.pdf) shows that the 74151 is a *digital* multiplexer:

[image]

In particular, it includes internal logic that buffers one of the inputs as a TTL-level output on the output pin, and as a result, it cannot be used as a demultiplexer. Attempting to apply a low-impedance source to the Y pin may cause damage to the source or the pin's driver.

You will need to use a digital *de*multiplexer, or an analog mux/switch such as the 4051.

Comment: Any workaround? Using which I can control those 8 leds??

Comment: @GavinBelson Without knowing what equipment and parts you have on hand, there isn't anything particular I can suggest.

Comment: @GavinBelson You could get a demultiplexer.